# test in Angular app

Tags: angular

I have a problem when running `ng test` in my terminal. the error is

> "Type 'FormGroup' is not assignable to type 'FormArray'

.
  Types of property `'controls'` are incompatible.
"

how can I address this problem?
------------------------------------------/this is a class which provide me an issue-----------------

This is the code

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { SharedModule } from '../../../../shared/shared.module';

import { FormGroup, Validators, FormControl, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';
import { StepAvailabilityComponent } from './step-availability.component';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

describe('StepAvailabilityComponent', () => {
  let component: StepAvailabilityComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<StepAvailabilityComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [ StepAvailabilityComponent ],
        imports: [SharedModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));enter code here

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(StepAvailabilityComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
      component.fg = new FormGroup({operatingDays: new FormArray(
          [
          new FormGroup({
              enabled: new FormControl(false),
              localName: new FormControl('mandag'),
          }),
          ]
      )});
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
```

Comment: We will also need the code of your tested component

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!I edited the description of the question to make it clearer and fast readable comments and codes so more people with knowledge of the subject will see it.  
 Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good luck!